# Unable to upload .tar.gz file greater than 500Mb

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, axios, javascript-objects

I want to upload a .tar.gz file (>500mb) to a URL using javascript.

Here is my approach

```
async uploadMapFile(url, FilePath, mapType) {
  try {
    let body = await _fs.promises.readFile(FilePath);
    let contentType =
      mapType === "navi" ? "application/zip" : "application/tar+gzip";
    const { data } = await axios.put(url, body, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": process.env.APP_ORIGIN,
        "Content-Type": contentType,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      }
    });

    console.log("After uploading file", data, mapType);
    //Removing the uploaded folder
    await this.afterFileUpload(mapType);
    this.store.mapUploadFlag = false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.store.mapUploadFailed = true;
  }
},
```

Using the above code I can upload smaller files but not able to upload larger files.
In case of larger files, the app crashes.

I am doing this uploading thing from the client side only.
By selecting a file by user we can upload.
Is there any workaround so we can upload by giving the file path?

Comment: "*the app crashes*" - Are you receiving any errors? If so, then please add the error inside the question as well

Comment: First it is a good idea to split the file in [chunks](https://medium.com/@selvakumar.ponnusamy/uploading-large-files-in-js-9f5de691353a). I think there are 2 possibilities for the crash: either JS is failing or the server is not configured to accept such large files. I suppose it is the later. PHP [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) says 2MB is default upload size.

Comment: @DarkBee I am not receiving any errors. using postman I can upload files.

Comment: @NileshMishra Using postman does not have anything to do with getting errors. Postman will receive the same errors as any other client and will not change the error behavior of the API given identical requests.

Comment: @possum I am trying to say that API is working fine . Using Postman I am able to upload the same .tar.gz files, but using javascript my app is getting crash without giving any error .

Comment: What environment is this running in? Clientside browser? Serverside node?  The usage of readFile suggests the latter, but your tagging of "reactjs" and "vue.js" suggests the prior? "crashing" without any error message seems rather strange for either environment. Have you tried attaching a debugger and stepping through?

Comment: @derpirscher It's running on the client side. It's working fine for small-size files and issues with large-size files only.

Comment: if that's running on the clientside, then what is `_fs.promises.readFile(FilePath)`? Some wrapper around the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API?

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks! . Using FileReader API It's working Now. You can add this to the answer.

Comment: Another explanation could be a client timeout, have you tried timing when the upload fails ? if its always after a specific number of seconds, it could be a parameter in axios.

Comment: @madgangmixers can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: You can set a timeout in Axios, even though it's 0 (disabled) by default. See the doc here : https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config

Comment: Here also : https://axios-http.com/docs/instance.
It shows the timeout can be configured at the Axios object creation.